# 'Dollar sign' alternative in jqwidgets

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

Do we have any alternative of `$` in JQWIDGETS? I have tried using jquery but it does not work. It is creating problem while using jquery and `jqWidgets` in same page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

More info https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/